# AndroidX Room unresolved supertypes RoomDatabase

Tags: android, kotlin, compiler-errors

When I'm trying to build my app I got this compilation error:

```
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
com.example.persistence.AppDatabase, unresolved supertypes: androidx.room.RoomDatabase
```

Persistence setup is in separate Android module (persistence).

build.gradle

```
// Kotlin StdLib
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

// Room
implementation      "androidx.room:room-runtime:$androidXRoom"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$androidXRoom"
implementation      "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$androidXRoom"
```

ext.androidXRoom = "2.1.0-alpha02"

I tried to change kotlin version, room version, back to Android Arch Room, but it's not working. I also tried cleaning project and invalidating cache of Android Studio. But it's not working.

edit: AppDatabase source

```
package com.example.persistence.db

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.example.persistence.post.PostDbDao
import com.example.persistence.post.PostDbEntity

@Database(entities = [PostDbEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun favoritePostsDao(): PostDbDao

    companion object {

        var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase? {
            if(INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(AppDatabase::class) {
                     INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "post_db").build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }

        fun destroy() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the AppDatabase class in the question

Comment: added AppDatabase class

Comment: Please add this: `annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // use kapt for Kotlin` and try.

Comment: But I have this added to build.gradle. I am using kapt because I am writing the app in Kotlin

Comment: are you sure that you have the correct imports?

Comment: I think imports are correct. Aren't them?

Comment: Can you add AppDatabase imports in the question add the full file

Comment: Added the full file

Comment: @jarekbutek Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem more likely lays with how you're defining your dependencies, `RoomDatabase` is part of the public API since your `AppDatabase` extends it and you presumably use that class in your downstream dependencies. However `RoomDatabase` is declared as a implementation-only dependency. This means that the class isn't normally available for the downstream dependencies during compilation.

Try changing `"androidx.room:room-runtime:$androidXRoom"` to the `api` configuration so it becomes part of the public API. That should probably resolve the error you're experiencing.

Answer (score 30):

Change gradle dependencies like

```
   REMOVE -> implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$androidXRoom"
   REPLACE WITH -> api "androidx.room:room-runtime:$androidXRoom"
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The other answers would compile, but defeats the point of having a separate module for your database/persistence functions.

You should not be exposing your Room Entity or Room database outside of your `persistence` module. Instead, you should write a function in your `persistence` module that maps your `PostEntity` @Entity into a simple `Post` data class.

I wrote about it in more detail here: https://jacquessmuts.github.io/post/modularization_room/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers. When I chose Module-> Android Library while creating a new module, the "api" process was successfully completed and I provided a solution.